# Sound changes pitch upon converting and playback

Tags: audio

I have a piece of music, and whenever it is converted (f.ex. from .ogg to .mp3) or played back by certain software, it changes to a higher pitch, and also seems to have its frequencies distorted.

What properties, or possible damage, to the sound file could be causing this to happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? What file type are you starting with and what program are you converting with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file headers may be 1) wrong, or 2) at an uncommon bitrate/frequency that some software cannot handle.
If you can get it to transcode to wav, aif, etc at the correct pitch, I'd use that as your new 'master' version.

[MediaInfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) (Freeware, multi-platform) might help to figure out what the headers say - though if they are corrupted, that info in itself might not help.
*Edit - I just checked, Mac v1.0 is no longer freeware, $2.99 from Mac App Store, older & other platform versions are still available, still free)*

[Header Investigator](http://www.railjonrogut.com/HeaderInvestigator.htm) (Freeware, Win only) can change WAV file headers